# What can I do to gain weight?

Tags: weight-gain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I gain weight and muscle weight?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-gain-weight-and-muscle-weight)

I am 23 years old. My height is 182cm and my weight is 65kg. My friends and relatives say that I am looking thin and need to put on some weight. Do I really need to put on weight? If yes then how?

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate of the other one. It's not that significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

According to your height and weight, your BMI (Body Mass Index) is [19.6](http://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_BMI/metric_bmi_calculator/results_normal.html?kg=65&meters=1.82) which in the Normal Range.  BMI is a good indicator of weight ranges, although not as accurate for very muscular people or for people with muscle wasting.

Other parameters you may want to check are your [body fat percentage](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Body-Fat-Percentage-Chart.html#Women) and [waist measurments](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Waist-Measurements.html) (waist circumference - ~ 88.9 cm to 101.6 cm or less, waist to height ratio - 0.55 or less).

If the numbers place you in a normal range, then you don't need to gain weight from a health standpoint.  If you do want to gain, add lean muscle mass, not fat.

Comment: [BMI is not appropriate for health or weight assessments of any kind](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3364/1771).

Comment: @Dave, I understand your point & I did include some of its limitations, & combined it with body fat percentages & waist measurements.  When used as one of the assessment tools, combined with other measurements, risk factors etc. it can be a helpful screening/population assessment tool.  [Studies](http://www.scientificjournals.org/journals2008/articles/1390.pdf) do show that if the BMI does not indicate obesity, there is a high correlation that you aren't obese.  However, a BMI indicating obesity tends to only identify 1 in 2 or 3 people who are obese as indicated by skinfold measurements.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy, I agree with Dave's post that BMI is not an appropriate measure for health or weight.  Otherwise almost all professionals athletes would be considered out of shape.  Take a 6'4" guy who weighs 265pds, has unbelievable body composition but doesn't adher to the numbers on a BMI scale.  Consider him obsese??

Comment: @Andreas, the BMI is clearly not intended for professional athletes due to their musculature. BMI calculators generally specify that it is not accurate for muscular people or people with muscle wasting.  It is a screening/ assessment tool used for the general population that is cheaper and easier and thus more readily available than providing large populations (not professional athletes) with caliper, DEXA or underwater weighing. If you put too much importance on the BMI, or rely on it ultimately then I agree that it is not useful.  But used as intended it can be the first step in screening.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy well put.  According to what you mentioned I completely agree that it is a better assessment for the general population.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not convinced that BMI is any better than a visual appraisal. The fact that it doesn't take fat mass into account *at all* means it's a poor proxy for the indicators we actually want to measure.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann BMI is a bunch of BS I believe. The morphology of each individual is so varying and different you can't compare yourself to a scaled chart. Bottom line is regular activity and a balanced diet develops the healthy individual. Going into science for sedentary computer junkies is a waste of time IMO. First go out and lift, run, swim, jump, eat clean then worry about figures like BMI...

Answer (score 0):

If you are underweight, for which you and your doctor are the only people who can judge, you need to lift heavy and eat big:

### 1. Stimulate Growth

Either buy a barbell and a power rack, or join a gym that has one. Get a copy of [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) and start lifting heavy. Compound exercises stimulate growth. Squats, chin-ups, deadlifts and presses will tell your body that it needs to get bigger.

### 2. Provide Fuel for Growth

Eat a ton of food. Real food is far superior to processed crap, but you'll need to eat a lot. Your best bets are high-animal-protein items like meat, eggs, milk, and fish. You'll also do well to take in a large amount of vegetables and good fats like coconut and olive oil, and avocado. Eating a lot of food will provide the raw materials your body needs to make you bigger.

If someone else cooks for you, you have a choice: 1) man up and learn to cook, 2) try to convince that person to change their cooking for you, or 3) remain undersized.