# 26 old 6 height 105 LBS. Worried about my weight

Tags: weight-gain, body-fat

I am 26 MALE, Height 6 FT, and my weight is 105LBS. I have been skinny my whole life. I gone through a lot in my life. alot of insults, everybody laughs at me. I want to end all of this now. I want to gain weight quickly. I am going to marry in next 2 years. Suggest me. I can spend any amount of money. Money is not a problem for me.

Thanks

Comment: If you have lots of money, find a professional. Not your local trainer, but a professional. Besides that, your question is really not very well-formulated. Is your major goal to pack on muscles? (Or just any mass?...) How often can you train? etc.

Comment: As soccerman has said please input what exactly do you want?(mass,muscle etc.)Also please give how much dedication are you ready to give(no of hrs per day,space ,time constraints if any,opting for a personal trainer or a local trainer nearby ) or else I have to flag this question.(don't want to flag as you are newbie and haven't read the help>tour,FAQ's section going by your question format)

Comment: Just eat more..

Comment: I would recommend getting medical advice.  This seems dangerously underweight, and I would not be surprised if there is an underlying medical issue.  You have a BMI of 14.24 which is way under the underweight category (18.5).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-gain-weight-and-muscle-weight

Comment: Do let me know if my advice worked for you. And the improvements you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand what you are feeling. What I am able to understand are the following points:

1. wants to gain weight
2. have two years time

My first suggestion would be to get a membership of a gym having adequate free weights and machines. There are few important things that you should look for : squat machine, Olympic rod, flat bench , incline bench, leg press machine, pull up bar, parallel bar for dips. The idea is to start with compound movements that target multiple joints/body parts. Three primary large body parts that constitute majority of the body are chest , back and legs. Training these would produce more testosterone and help you in gain more mass, but said that small body parts like biceps , triceps , shoulders  and trapezius are of equal importance and should not be neglected. Exercises that you should be focusing are :

- Bench press, flat and incline
- Squats
- leg press
- Dead lift
- Pull ups
- Barbell curls
- Triceps Extensions
- Overhead military press

But it goes without saying that these are to be performed with absolute form and without any cheating . With time good form will become habit and that will define your gains.Body weight exercise like pull ups won't be easy in the beginning , so perform lat pull down on machine , and as you progress in this exercise you should be able to perform more number of pull ups.Get at least six months of membership of the gym, and be patient, you will be able to see the changes.Limit your cardio , but do not completely eliminate them. Once or twice should be enough.

Second suggestion to increase the number of carbohydrates, protein, and fats in your diet.Include whole eggs ,milk, fish, sweet potato , chicken, brown rice, legumes , nuts, fruits like pomegranate, banana , cottage cheese and you can also include red meat like beef in your diet.Make sure that you are having meat at least once in your daily diet . Considering that the fact that you are taller , you have to really focus on the diet and if you get this correctly , then you have won the war. Introduce changes to your diet slowly and not in one go, so that your body can get adapted to it.I won't recommend supplements so early in your diet , but later on , like after five six months later you can go for mass gainer, one that I would personally recommend is the Ultimate nutrition iso mass gainer , which I believe is one of the best mass gainer. Alcohol and processed foods should be limited and are allowed only once or twice a week.

Thirdly make sure you are getting eight hours of sleep.

Fourth , be patient,and don't give up , with hard work and proper nutrition you will be able to achieve your goals.Focus on proper diet from day one , and you will be able to see the results.Remember that what you are doing , is doing for your self and not for anyone else , so don't compare with others and don't get intimidated by others.

Comment: And see a doctor to rule out a condition limiting your weight. There are lots of conditions that can keep you from gaining weight, so it would be better to check for and, if necessary, treat them before you waste time trying to do something that may not be possible in your current condition.